# How to convert an arithmetic expression of a string type to an integer in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, integer, expression

This is my code after running this piece of code, I am getting exception:

```
    fun main() {
    var str = "(100 + 50)/2"
    
    var sum = str.toInt()
    
    println(sum)
    }
```

Exception with stack trace is given below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(100 + 50)/2"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (:-1) 
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt (:-1) 
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt (:-1)
```

Comment: There's no native way to parse a mathematical expression. You need to manually parse it yourself or use a library like `exp4j`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot evaluate arithmetic in string expressions natively in kotlin or java. Either use a library (like [exp4j](https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/), [Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/), and [SEpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)) or write your own ([refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)).