# Symbolic equations in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I solve symbolic equations in kotlin.
Like in sympy I need to know how can i solve an equation like this one 2x-3=67. Just an example.

I need to know please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410129/how-to-convert-an-arithmetic-expression-of-a-string-type-to-an-integer-in-kotlin

Comment: is power of x always 1?